# How to get a certain part of a linked list

Tags: c#, inheritance, doubly-linked-list

I have a project at my university and I stumbled upon a problem I am not able to solve.

About the program: I need to create a list of tasks(they can be private or business tasks). I need a function that returns a list of ONLY private tasks and another function that returns a list of ONLY business tasks. 
So I have a class "Task" that contains "next" and "prev" connections. The classes "PrivateTask" and "BusinessTask" inherit this class. I also have a class ToDoList where I actually try to create the list.

```
class ToDoList
{

    Task first = null;
    Task last = null;

    //adds new tasks and sorts them right away
    public void AddSorted(Task newTask)
    {
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = newTask;
            last = newTask;
        }
        else
        {
            if(newTask < first)
            {
                Prepend(newTask);
            }
            else if(newTask > last)
            {
                Append(newTask);
            }
            else
            {
                Task loopTask = first;

                while(newTask > loopTask)
                {
                    loopTask = loopTask.next;
                }
                AddBefore(loopTask, newTask);
            }
        }

    }

    //adds a new task before another chosen task
    private void AddBefore(Task Next, Task newTask)
    {
        newTask.prev = Next.prev;
        newTask.next = Next;
        Next.prev.next = newTask;
        Next.prev = newTask;
    }

    //adds at the start of the list
    private void Prepend(Task newTask)
    {
        first.prev = newTask;
        newTask.next = first;
        first = newTask;
    }

    //adds at the end of the list
    private void Append(Task newTask)
    {
        last.next = newTask;
        newTask.prev = last;
        last = newTask;
    }
```

And now I need to return a list of BusinessTasks

```
//returns a list of business tasks
public ToDoList GetBusinessList()
{
    ToDoList busList = new ToDoList();
    Task loopTask = first;

    while(loopTask != null)
    {
        if(loopTask is BusinessTask)
        {
            busList.AddSorted(loopTask);
        }
        loopTask = loopTask.next;
    }
    return busList;
}
```

But when I return this list the whole content of the main list synchronizes with this one and I cannot understand why.

Comment: You need to add a _copy_ of the task to the new list, otherwise changing the `next` reference changes the task in both lists.

Comment: Matt has already given you an answer but if you found this interesting have a look at the .net implementation of [LinkedList](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f) I might look a bit strange at first but you will notice some familiar stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't putting *copies* of your tasks into your new list, you are putting *references* into the new list. As a result, you are changing the *same objects*. So when you push an item from your first list into the second list and as a result `next` and/or `prev` gets changed, you are changing both lists.

So you need to *copy* the item from your original list and put the new item in the second list.

```
while(loopTask != null)
{
    if(loopTask is BusinessTask)
    {
        var clone = loopTask.Clone();
        busList.AddSorted(clone);
    }
    loopTask = loopTask.next;
}
```

Now obviously you'll need to implement a `Clone` method that will copy all the properties *except* those that relate to the position in the list (`prev` and `next`) to a new instance of `BusinessTask`

Now if you actually want to have the object in both lists to be references to the *same object*. So that changing a property on one will change the other, then you can get clever by separating out the *data* part from the list *node* part. So you could do something like:

```
public class TaskBase
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Node 
{
    public TaskBase Data { get; private set;}
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public Node Prev { get; set; }

    public Node(TaskBase data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public Node Clone()
    {
        // Now all the data part is the same object
        // so changing Data.SomeProperty in one list will be 
        // reflected in both. But the Next and Prev properties
        // are independent. 
        return new Node(Data);
    }
}
```

And then your loop might look like this:

```
while(loopTask != null)
{
    if(loopTask.Data is BusinessTask)   // assuming BusinessTask derives from BaseTask
    {
        var clone = loopTask.Clone();
        // clone contains the same BusinessTask, but it's position in the new list
        // won't mess up the old list.
        busList.AddSorted(clone);
    }
    loopTask = loopTask.next;
}
```

Comment: @Romoku: Cheers